# Where is the game logic supposed to be in the Model-View ViewModel pattern in android

Tags: java, android, mvvm, architecture

I'm currently developing a poker game app for android using the Model-View ViewModel pattern and I'm not sure where the correct place for the game logic should be. The architecture looks currently something like this:

```
GameActivity --> GameViewModel --> Repository --> Database
                      |    ^
                      |    :
                      |    :
                      |-> PokerGame
```

The GameViewModel calls PokerGame Methods for initialising the game and passing interactions by the player.
The PokerGame is observed by the GameViewModel. The PokerGame has an internal Thread which runs until the game is over and frequently passes data to the GameViewModel, like the current distribution of jetons.

Im working with Room and LiveData, so the GameActivity always triggers when changes are made to the database.

What would be a better approach, should the Repository hold the PokerGame instead?

Comment: In your graphic its not really MVC is it? You don't have a Controller

Comment: No this is supposed to implement the MVVM pattern rather than the MVC pattern

Comment: "should the Repository hold the GameActivity instead - No". A Repository is part of the domain logic, firmly in the "model" part of MVVM. As its a lower component it should not know about higher level classes like the `View`.  Currently your view model will be interacting with the repository so this will doing the business logic (some times its better to create abstractions here as described by Robert Martin as Interactors / Use Cases) - IMO

Comment: @Mark thanks for your answere, seems like I made a big typo. The correct question would be, if the Repository should hold the PokerGame instead of the GameViewModel?

Comment: Again - No - Your respository is just keeping current and aggrregate information from each completed game / player so when a game is completed and a new game started some historical information can be persisted or some similar use cases? .. it shouldn't depend on a game itself? If you think it should then it might make sense to look at your code to make sure you have seperated concerns correctly and then write some behavioural tests.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @Mark , it should be clear now

Answer (score 1):

In a simple MVVM pattern you got the presentation layer (view and viewmodel) and the data layer (the repository and datasources, e.g. database in your case).

A game logic is somehow a business or domain logic. Now the presentation is just presenting or showing informations to a user. ViewModels should be as dumb as possible. They only show concrete data of the model. On the otherside data should not know about any higher logic either.

As Mark stated the repository can be seen as domain logic. So in your case the correct place would be the repository.

The repository is (often) seen as part of the data layer to just fetch data (from local database or remote network). That is why i use a domain layer with UseCases.

UseCases have one single usecase and can connect to several repositories to fullfill several task, like setting up a new game, saving a game's state, loading a game, manipulate the game, ending a game's turn and so on. In fact my use cases are often very thin, so that my usecases have an instance of the game engine and the engine connects to any repository if needed.